# Difference between returning *this and this - c++

Tags: c++

```
Class A{
//Code...
A& operator++(){
//code..
return ____;
}

A operator++(){
//code..
return ___;
}
```

When am I supposed to return `*this` or `this`?

I do understand `this` is a pointer, and `*this` is the de-reference of the pointer, but when the function expects a value by reference, or by value, I am having trouble to decide what to return.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` is of type `A*` in your functions, so that would be an inappropriate type to return.

`*this` is of type `A&` in your function, and that can *bind* either to `A&` or `A`. When overloading the prefix `++` operator as you're doing, returning `A&` is the normal return type of the function.

Comment: @maor36a Look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access under "Built-in indirection operator" for reference.

Comment: So in case I'm on the A& case, returning THIS would be wrongful, and I'll have to return *THIS?

Comment: @maor36a Yes, in both of the functions you listed, trying to return `this` will give a compile error, while returning `*this` will work.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: both return types `A` and `A&` require to return `*this`. If there was a return type `A*` it would require to return `this`.

The class can return either `A` or `A&` but its behaviour will change. If the return type is `A` the class will create a copy of itself and return it; if the return type is `A&` the class will return a reference to itself.

So it depends on the design of the class. Usually `operator++` returns the class value after incrementing it, so a logical design would be first to increment it (whatever it means) and then return a reference.

Comment: "So it depends" - what's "it" ? Whether to use `this` or `*this` does not depend on the design of the class here. Both cases require `*this`.

Comment: I guess that returning by-reference or by-value depends on whether I create a new object, or not.
My meaning is, in case I do create a new object, returning it by-reference would be pointless, due the fact it'd be destroyed and return garabe-contecnt as soon as I get out of the function.
If I only change an existing object, then returning it by-refernce would make more sense.

Comment: @MSalters yes, both cases require `*this`, I focused only on the return type. I will edit the answer.

Comment: @maor36a yes, if you return a temporary object by reference `A&` it will go out of scope as soon as the callee operator returns and the caller code will have undefined behaviour. But remember that if the return type is `const A&` then you can return a temporary object as its life time will be expanded to its usage.